# Returning a generic IList causing an error

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, ilist, contravariance

I have the following structure:

```
public class MyBaseClass : IGeneralClass
{
}

public class MyClass : MyBaseClass 
{
    ...
}

public class MyDataClass
{
    private List<MyClass> _data = null;  

    public void PopulateData()
    {
        ...
    }

    public IList<IGeneralClass> Data
    {
        get 
        {
            return (IList<IGeneralClass>)_data;
        }
    }

}
```

I was under the impression that I could do this in .Net4.5 because of contravariance, but when I try, I get a runtime error as follows:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyClass]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[IGeneralClass]'.
```

Am I casting this incorrectly, or is this not supported?

Comment: It's not allowed because otherwise the `Add()` method would allow you to (for example) add a `Cat` to a list of `Dog` if both classes derived from `Animal` and you assigned the `List<Dog>` to a `List<Animal>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was under the impression that I could do this in .Net4.5 because of contravariance,

You mean covariance, contravariance is the other way around, when `A` is a subtype of `B`, therefore `X<B>` is a subtype of `X<A>` (as is the case of `Action<in T>`).

[`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6(v=vs.110).aspx) is invariant though - notice how there's no `in` or `out` modifiers. You may be mistaking it for [`IEnumerable<out T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx), which is covariant.

Why is it invariant, I hear you ask? An `IList<Dog>` cannot be treated as an `IList<Animal>`, otherwise this would have to cause a runtime error:

```
var listAnimals = listDogs as IList<Animal>();
listAnimals.Add(cat);
```

Comment: You're absolutely right - I needed IEnumerable.  Many thanks.